# How do I get refs and computed vars to show up in Vue Devtools when using the Composition API and the Script Setup syntax?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-devtools

I have a number of variables in one of my components that would go in the `data()` function or `computed: {}` section when using Vue's Options API (which I'm more familiar with), but this component is using the Composition API and the `<script setup>` syntax, and I'm not seeing the variables show up in Vue Devtools, despite the fact that the props and refs *are* showing up.

What do I need to do to get these variables to show up in the Vue Devtools?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did see my variables showing in the setup section of the dev tool. Btw my dev tool version is 3.2.45. Might be you need to update it

Comment: @Duannx Thanks for the reply.  I'm seeing the latest version of the devtools as being 6.4.5, which is what I have.  Also, were you using the `<script setup>` syntax in your component?

Comment: @Duannx I just upgraded Vue to version `3.2.45` and I'm still having the issue.

Comment: Yeah. I'm using `script setup` syntax. Sorry for my first comment. Actually, my Vue version is `3.2.45` and the dev tool version is `6.4.5`. I saw you have the same config. I'm afraid that I can't help more. You should create a discussion on vue devtool GitHub to get help from maintainers https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/discussions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is a known bug with version `6.4.5` of the Vue Devtools for *imported* components that use the `<script setup>` syntax: https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/issues/1940

There is a PR to fix the issue here: https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-vue/pull/81

Until that fix is available, the workaround is to use the `defineComponent` syntax for those imported components (assuming you can change their code).